# Bound the converging series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty ((\frac{n^3+2n+1}{n^3+n+1})^{1/3}-1)^{3/4} $

I created a graph and it seems like $ \frac{1}{n} $, but as i know this series should converge. Can't prove it with any usual rules, seems like i have to bound it with another converging function, but couldn't find anything better than $ \frac{1}{n}^{3/4} $, which is obviously don't converge.

$ ((1 +\frac{n}{n^3+n+1})^{1/3}-1)^{3/4} $ is like the most obvious step, but doesn't go that well afterwards. Any throughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Taylor expansions around $0$: as $n\to\infty$, $1/n\to 0$, and so
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{n^3+2n+1}{n^3+n+1} &= \frac{1+2/n^2+1/n^3}{1+1/n^2+1/n^3} = \frac{1+2/n^2+o(1/n^2)}{1+1/n^2+o(1/n^2)} \\&= \left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) \\&= 1+\frac{1}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align*}$$
*(we used the Taylor expansion, to first order, of $\frac{1}{1-u}$ when $u\to 0$)* from which
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{n^3+2n+1}{n^3+n+1}\right)^{1/3} -1
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)^{1/3} -1
= 1+\frac{1}{3n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)-1 = \frac{1}{3n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align*}$$
*(we used the Taylor expansion, to first order, of $(1+u)^\alpha$ when $u\to 0$)* and thus
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\left(\frac{n^3+2n+1}{n^3+n+1}\right)^{1/3} -1\right)^{3/4}
&= \frac{1}{3^{3/4}n^{3/2}}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\,.
\end{align*}$$
You can now conclude by the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), since you get
$$
\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\left(\left(\frac{n^3+2n+1}{n^3+n+1}\right)^{1/3} -1\right)^{3/4}}{\frac{1}{3^{3/4}n^{3/2}}} =1}
$$
and the denominator is positive.

Answer (score 0):

We know that
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{x/3}-1}{x}  = 1/3 $$
So we can take $x=\ln(\frac{n^3+2n+1}{n^3+n+1}) $. And we know that
$$ \lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+y)}{y} = 1 $$
So we can take $y=\frac{n+1}{n^3+n+1}$

Which we can compare further to $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Then by taking the power of $3/4$, we can compare the whole sum to $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, so it's convergent